# How old is R2-D2 and where did he originate?

Tags: star-wars, age, r2-d2

C3PO's (improbable) creation is featured in the *Star Wars* films but what about R2-D2? Is there any source (probably outside the films) that explains where he (it) came from and how old he is?

Comment: I vaguely remember reading somewhere that he was over 100 years old, but don't know where.

Comment: What? I don't remember C3PO's creation anywhere. What Star Wars are you talking about? Are you one of those delluded fools that keep telling me insane things about some prequels that don't exist? :P What are you trying to fool me with next? There are sequels to The Matrix?

Comment: C3 was not created in the movies, he was extensively repaired.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

R2D2 was essentially a generic astromech droid. He was purchased as a maintenance droid for the Queen's ship, one of several. He was brand new, one owner, at the start of Phantom Menace. He may have been on the ship for a few months, but not much longer.

His first mention in the Star Wars universe (according to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R2-D2), which takes into account the Extended Universe) is his appearance in Episode I.
R2D2 was basically a standard droid who developed his personality and status over time as he became involved in the major events. Nothing quite so colourful as C3PO's origin story.

Droids in the Star Wars universe are occasionally memory wiped so not to build up personality quirks, this hasn't happened to R2-D2, but it explains why he is *unique*.

Comment: Also droid in the Star Wars universe are occasionally memory wiped so not to build up personality quirks.

Comment: R2D2 was purchased as a maintenance droid for the Queen's ship, one of several.  He was brand new, one owner, at the start of Phantom Menace.  He may have been on the ship for a few months, but not much longer.

Comment: How do we know that he was first bought for the Queen's ship?

Answer (score 11):

According to LucasFilm Timeline, R2D2 was manufactured just before 32 BBY (Before Battle of Yavin). Manufacturer: Industrial Automaton

Reference of BBY from movie:
1. The Battle to destroy Death Star in *Star Wars - A New Hope (Episode IV)* is known as Battle of Yavin.
2. The movie story of *Star Wars - The Phantom Menace (Episode I)* was happened in 32 BBY.

Comment: How do we know that?

Answer (score -5):

R2D2 is exactly 66 years old, because The *Force Awaken* happens 34 years after *A New Hope*, which happens 32 years after *The Phantom Menace*. It says that he was built right before *The Phantom Menace* started. So from there we have to count the dates between the movies and there we go.

Comment: ***Where*** does it say that he was built just before The Phantom Menace?

Comment: As Valorum said, please try and provide sources for our answer :)